# Svg could be displayed when added directly to the dom but not when its base64 converted string is passed as an img source

Tags: javascript, html, svg, base64

I have made [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-greider-bhdcy?file=/src/index.js:199-258) in which an svg could be displayed when it's added directly to the dom
but when i try to get the base64 string like this

```
const base64svg = `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${btoa(mySvg)}`;
```

and then pass it to an img src attribute like this

```
<img src="'+ base64svg + '" width="600" height="600"></img>
```

It doesn't work!
Why?!

Comment: Because dataURIs want some characters escaped; I recall escaping **<** and **>** is enough... but I could be wrong

Comment: I don't have the most beefy laptop. I'm really struggling just displaying the SVG document (around 9 Mb...) in my browser. Could you test your setup with a smaller SVG?

Comment: @chrwahl i had problem only with that svg which has special é characters and maybe others but also the encoding="UTF-8" so it's supposed to work. Now i tried without btoa and it seems better